# .htaccess - Require a PHP file if directory don't exist

Tags: php, .htaccess, routes, require

I want to require a PHP File with a get parameter if and only if someone request a URL without any extension like .php and .html etc (i.e. directory) and that directory also don't exist.

For Example : 
`example.com/xyz`
now there is no `xyz` directory on server then .htaccess requires a php file with get parameter - `myfile.php?url=xyz`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but if i request xyz?id=1 it still send only xyz. Is there any way to
>   send whole string no matter what is string

As you mentioned if you request `example.com/xyz` or `example.com/xyz?id=1` you want to get all the parameters. Then use this. Notice the `QSA` flag. That will append the requested query string. I think this is the answer you're looking for.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /myfile.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

So if you request this `example.com/xyz?id=1&h=2`

Your PHP `print_r($_GET);` output will be this.

```
Array ( [url] => xyz [id] => 1 [h] => 2 )
```

Comment: awesome thanks .. one word changed whole program :)

Answer (score 0):

start with this snippet

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ myfile.php?url=$1 [PT,L]
    ErrorDocument 404 /myfile.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thank You So Much :) It Works.. but if i request `xyz?id=1` it still send only `xyz`. Is there any way to send whole string no matter what is string?

Comment: you have to write (or find) url parser function. you can only get parameters with .htaccess... xyz here is not parameter, this file name or part of query string... google this "php url parser"